# Questions about Munkres’ proof that the real line is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation, connectedness

I was reading Munkres' proof that the real line is connected and I have had a lot of trouble understanding it. Particularly why there are two cases one being that the $\sup A_0$ belongs in $B_0$ and the other being that the $\sup A_0$ belongs in $B_0$.

Also why is $d$ a smaller upper bound than $c$ in $A_0$? And where does the contradiction lead us?

I am really confused about this, so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is it $A^{\circ}$ or $A_0$ or some other notation?

Comment: The second one, I didn't know to write it in MathJax. I edited it now

Comment: Unfortunately, without including more specifics of Munkres’ proof, the only people who can help will be people with the book. You might want to name the book at the beginning of the question

Comment: (I mean, I took topology from Munkres himself way back in ‘88, and I’m not sure what book you are referencing.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews woah that’s actually super cool. but there is a book called munkres topology. it’s probably the second edition OP is referring to

Comment: Topology by Munkres, I think second edition

Comment: @CSquared Yes that is the one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aiming to get a contradiction, Munkres starts with a separation $\{A_0,B_0\}$ of the interval $[a,b]$, where $a\in A_0$ and $b\in B_0$. Because we’re working in the linear continuum $L$, we know that $\sup A_0$ exists. Since $A_0\subseteq[a,b]$, we know that $a\le x\le b$ for each $x\in A_0$, so $a\le\sup A_0\le b$. Let $c=\sup A_0$; then $c\in[a,b]=A_0\cup B_0$. Moreover, $A_0\cap B_0=\varnothing$ so either $c\in A_0$, or $c\in B_0$. Munkres will get a contradiction by showing that in fact neither of these is possible: $c\notin A_0$, and $c\notin B_0$; his *Case* $\mathit{1}$ is the proof that $c\notin B_0$, and his *Case* $\mathit{2}$ is the proof that $c\notin A_0$. Each of these is itself a proof by contradiction.

The quantity $d$ appears in *Case* $\mathit{1}$, in which we’re trying to prove that $c\notin B_0$. To get a contradiction, we suppose that $c\in B_0$. In particular this means that $c\ne a$, since $a\in A_0$, so either $c=b$, or $a<c<b$. By hypothesis $B_0$ is open in $[a,b]$, so in either case there a $d<c$ such that $(d,c]\subseteq B_0$.

Now suppose that $x\in A_0$. If $x>d$, then either $x\in(d,c]\subseteq B_0$, which is impossible, or $x>c$, which is also impossible, so in fact $x\le d$. And $x$ was an arbitrary element of $A_0$, so every element of $A_0$ is less than $d$, and therefore $d$ is an upper bound for $A_0$, contradicting the fact that $c$ is the **least** upper bound of $A_0$. This contradiction shows that there cannot be an element $d\in[a,b]$ such that $d<c$ and $(d,c]\subseteq B_0$. But $B_0$ is open, so if $c\in B_0$, there **must** be such a $d$, and therefore $c$ cannot be in $B_0$ after all.

In *Case* $\mathit{2}$ Munkres goes on to show, again by contradiction, that $c$ cannot be in $A_0$, either, and therefore cannot exist, contradicting the fact that it **must** exist, since $L$ is assumed to have the least upper bound property.

Comment: Isnt $c$ always in $A_0$ since it is its $sup$ ?

Comment: @GeorgeRevingston: No. E.g., $1=\sup(0,1)$, but $1\notin(0,1)$.

Comment: Ooooh, thanks, that really clears things up

Comment: Thank you so much, finally it makes sense to me

Comment: @ChrisEwing: You’re very welcome.